# Speeding up generation of large array of Gaussian numbers using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

I need to draw a large number of samples (30 million) from a Gaussian distribution. Using numpy, I use the following function call:

```
np.random.normal(1.2, 1.5, (30, 100, 100, 100, 1))
```

Using timeit, I find that this takes 828 ms. Since my processor runs at 2.5 GHz, this roughly takes 6700 cycles per sample. I feel this is too high. Is there a way to speed this up? I am even ready to use some other library if needed. I have already checked that I am using MKL on an Intel processor.

Comment: Did you see the following pages: [Multithreaded Generation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/multithreading.html) and an [updated version](https://github.com/fzeiser/numpy/blob/f6c9b22be0c0d47149e4c42b35d391ef194e93c1/doc/source/reference/random/multithreading.rst) of that page?

Comment: Not really, it does look good, and I will try!

Comment: Which function are you using? `np.random` is the whole module.

Comment: @Joe I am using np.random.normal. Fixing it in the question.

Comment: How did you calculate *cycles per sample*? If I do `2.5e9*0.828/30e6` I get `69` cycles per sample, which seems more reasonable

Comment: yes, 60 CPE is looking reasonable. RNG performance depends on many factors. You may check the performance in MKL Vector Statistics Random Number Generator Performance Data - https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-vsperfdata-uniform